# Computing a combined average (mean) of values

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics

My textbook on descriptive statistics says that when we have a data set of m members, the mean is calculated like this:

x-bar = 1/m (Σf<sub>i</sub>x<sub>i</sub>) where sigma sums values from 1 to k (we have k groups in our frequency table and x<sub>i</sub> is the representative of each group)

I get the idea, but it immediately asks the reader to prove that given a data set of m members with the mean value of x-bar and another data set of n members with the mean value of y-bar, the combined mean is calculable by the following formula: `[m(x-bar)+n(y-bar)]/m+n`

I tried to prove this by breaking it down to the definition but I simply can't get to the final formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know

$$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i \text{   and   } \bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n y_j.$$

So

$$\sum_{i=1}^m x_i = m\bar{x} \text{   and   } \sum_{j=1}^n y_j = n\bar{y}.$$

Then, calculating the mean of all $x_i, y_j$ directly:

$$\mu = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_m + y_1 + y_2 + ... + y_n}{m+n} = \frac{1}{m+n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n y_j\right) = \frac{m\bar{x} + n\bar{y}}{m+n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The mean of the new data set is 
$$\frac1{m+n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}f_ix_i+\sum_{i=1}^{j}g_iy_i\right)$$
where there $g_i$'s are the frequencies for the new data set and $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i+\sum_{i=1}^j g_i=n+m$. Also
$$n\bar{x}=\sum_{i=1}^kf_ix_i,\hspace{10mm}m\bar{y}=\sum_{i=1}^jg_iy_i$$
Therefore the new mean is
$$\frac{n\bar{x}+m\bar{y}}{m+n}$$

Comment: This hint is misleading since the coefficients f_i are not a priori the same in x-bar and in y-bar.

Comment: @Did, I felt somewhat uncomfortable fudging the indexes myself. I have fixed the indexes accordingly

Comment: I am afraid I am not sure that I can. If we have two data sets with different number of groups and  ranges, it doesn't seem quite right to substitute that z_i with (x_i + y_i) because then when I want to reconstruct individual sigmas, they would have indexes out of their predefined ranges: 1/(m+n)Σz_i = 1/(m+n)Σ(x_i+y_i) = 1/(m+n)[Σx_i + Σy_i] = 1/m+n[mx-bar + ny-bar] and the rest follows smoothly. but the individual sigmas will each have a range of 1 to m+n.

Comment: @JaneCute95, my bad. My notation was rather unfortunate. I have edited the answer to clarify my hint.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I still don't think that would resolve the fundamental indexing issue that comes up when we take it from the definition. The starting point is that we have m+n objects, for which the z-bar (the new combined mean), by definition can be calculated by z-bar = 1/(m+n)* Σz_i. That sigma has a range from 1 to m+n. How can you extract the two individual sigmas with the proper indices in your first line from Σ that has a different range.

Comment: @JaneCute95 see edit. I have not extracted the two sums. We know there is a total of $n+m$ objects. We also know the frequencies of each $x_i$ and $y_i$. Therefore we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{m+n}z_i=\sum_{i=1}^k f_ix_i+\sum_{i=1}^j g_iy_i$ because that is the definition of $z_i$, namely, the union of the x's and y's.

Comment: I accept the new indices in the individual Σ's, but then you assume that k=n and j=m, they are not necessarily the same (n* x-bar by definition is equal to Σf_i * x_i but the range of sigma is from 1 to n. You assume it is from 1 to k. It might not be).

Comment: @JaneCute95, no, read the second line. $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i+\sum_{i=1}^j g_i=n+m$